# Accessing from my login page to grafana page

Tags: authentication, session-variables, grafana

I have a question about accessing to Grafana.
I built the login form webpage using passport-local express in Node.js.
And **is there any ways to access Grafana page from my login webpage using session**?

Does anybody have an idea?
I can't find any in google.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not 100% sure I understand your question.

But you can use your app like a reverse proxy and send an auth-header to Grafana. http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/#auth-proxy

This way Grafana will create an user for you and all logins will go thru your application.

Comment: Thank you for replying me answer. I'll read that you linked ! :) If I have more questions, can I comment here? or should I use issues from grafana github? :D Thanks once again!

Comment: We have a mailinglist, irc channel and slack channel. You can find more info at http://grafana.org/community/ Asking questions on SO is also a good idea since others can read them as well :)